# GAE flexible runtime persistance of disk data

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, persistent-storage

I'm new to GCP and we are trying to scale up our apps. Our solution of choice would be to pack our existing software into containers and deploy them to app engine flexible. It would be all simple if not some services need persistent disk storage. For compute engine I found that persistent disk you can add to all your vm's, but I would like to have the scalability and simplicity of appengine flexible. When I look to there prices, there is an option next to cpu  and ram, which is named persistent storage. Can I assume, that all "instances" can access that part of the disk and it don't get lost. To make it more clear is it that persistent, that you can be confident to run some sort of database in it. Or is it possible to add a persistent disk to an appengine application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing to local disc is ephemeral in the Flexible Environment, as disk gets initialized on each VM startup. The VM instances used in the flexible environment are restarted on a weekly basis. During restarts, Google's management services apply any necessary operating system and security updates. You may read more detail in the "Choosing an App Engine Environment" [online document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments). You can use Cloud Storage to store and serve files. The "Using Cloud Storage" [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage) provides related information.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I thought.